# disable on-click mail sending in java mode

Tags: spacemacs, gnus, java

using `spacemacs` in java mode, moving the mouse over an email address displays in the modeline the text `mouse-1, C-c RET: mail this address`. And if I click on it, a blank email sending form is opened in emacs (strangely enough that doesn't happen in haskell mode or fundamental).

My issue is that while I don't use the mouse much when using emacs, I often use it to focus the emacs window. And if there's somehow an email address exactly where I click, I open that email compose buffer, which is never what I want, because (at this point) I don't use emacs for email sending.

How can I disable that "click to compose an email" feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer on `#emacs` on freenode. The suggestion was that presumably `goto-address-mode` should be related to the issue. It seems it's actually turned off in `java-mode` in my setup, however turning that minor mode off does fix the issue for me.

So the workaround is to put this in the `emacs` startup script (`.spacemacs` under spacemacs):

```
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook (lambda () (goto-address-mode -1)))
```

That does fix the issue for me.